# How to get links in each block PHP DomReady?

Tags: php, dom, domready

I have the following HTML DOM:

```
<div class="m">
<div class="cr"><a class="link" href="1">1</a><div class="title">1</div></div>
<div class="cr"><a class="link" href="2">2</a><div class="title">2</div></div>
<div class="cr"><a class="link" href="3">3</a><div class="title">3</div></div>
</div>
```

I need to get in one loop values: `.title` and `href` of links.

I tried:

```
$similar = $xpath->query('//div[@class = "cr"]');

foreach ($similar as $key => $item) {
    $href = ?
    $title = ?
}
```

Comment: ***"I need to get in one loop values: .title and href of links."*** But your `<a>` Tags (links) have neither **title** attribute nor a pre-defined **href** attribute. By **title**, are you implying the **css-classname** of the embedded `<div>` or the **title** Attribute of the Anchor tags **<a>** which do not exist in your code?

Comment: I can write two `$xpath->query` queries, but I can not join them in one loop

Comment: Great! Much better.... What about the `title`? Which title are you after? the Class: `.title` of the inner `<div>` or the title of the `<a>` Tag?

Comment: There is not `title`. I need go by all `class="cr"` and get from here `a.link` and `nodeValue`of `div.title`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You could use the `SimpleXMLElement` Class for that as demonstrated by the Snippet below which, you may [Quick-Test Here](https://eval.in/678575).

```
<?php

    $html = '<div class="m">
            <div class="cr"><a href="1">1</a><div class="title">1st Node Value</div></div>
            <div class="cr"><a href="2">2</a><div class="title">2nd Node Value</div></div>
            <div class="cr"><a href="3">3</a><div class="title">3rd Node Value</div></div>
            </div>';


    $sXML       = new SimpleXMLElement($html);
    $links      = $sXML->xpath("child::div/a");
    $titles     = $sXML->xpath("child::div/div");

    $arrLinks   = array();
    $arrTitles  = array();

    foreach($links as $link){
        $arrLinks[]     = (string)$link->xpath("attribute::href")[0];
    }

    foreach($titles as $title){
        $arrTitles[]    = (string)$title;
    }

    var_dump($arrLinks);        
    // YIELDS::
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '3' (length=1)

    var_dump($arrTitles);
    // YIELDS::
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1st Node Value' (length=14)
      1 => string '2nd Node Value' (length=14)
      2 => string '3rd Node Value' (length=14)
```